# EthersJS wont parse decimal

Tags: solidity, remix, ethers.js

I have a dapp that lets users gift their assets to others on a specified date. I am collecting the user data through a form before calling my smart contract. Now everything works fine except for the fact that when a user tries to create an "Ether Gift" using fractional ether value("0.1", "1.2"), etherjs cant seem to format it to ether and reverts with "invalid BigNumber string". What is perplexing is that, this function works with whole numbers(say 1 or 2 ether). Not sure what I am doing wrong here.
Also, calling the function with decimals works just fine in Remix.

Please find code below

```
  const handleCreateEtherGift = async () => {
    try {
      const amount = formData?.value;
      const etherCreateTransaction = await willsContract.createEtherGift(
        formData?.beneficiaryAddress,
        formData?.value,
        formData?.releaseDate,
        { value: ethers.utils.parseUnits(amount, 18) }
      );
      await etherCreateTransaction.wait();
      toast.success("Gifted Ether Successfully", toastStyles);
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error(`Ether Gift creation failed`, toastStyles);
      console.log(error.message)
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ethers.utils.parseEther()` function instead of `ethers.utils.parseUnits()`. [Check the documentation](https://docs.ethers.org/v4/api-utils.html).

Comment: Thanks. However, I have used the ParseEther method and it returns the same error.